# Can i add view to table row dynamically?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I am new in asp.net razor view and jquery. Now i have to add row to table dynamically.In this row have many thing to do.So i don't want to add with "Append()".Please Can i do it with another way?Can i split this to outside view and add this to table row?

Eng.

```
 $("#button").click(function () {
     $("#detailmain").append();
});
```

I want to add below code to table row.

```
<tr>
           <td>
               <table style="background-color: #FDE8D6;width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid silver">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/test.png" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            test form                          
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="2">
                            <table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
                                <tr style="height:30px;background:silver;">
                                    <td>
                                    Fef test
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table style="font-size:11px;width:100%;">

                                            <tr style="background:silver;">
                                                <th>
                                                    Current Worksheet
                                                </th>
                                                <th >
                                                    Detail Worksheet
                                                </th>
                                                <th>

                                                </th>
                                                <th>

                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    Date of Birth
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    Birthday
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    E
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    D
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    User Name
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    Name
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    E
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    D
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button style="width:100%;background:#0094ff;">Field</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background-color: #FDE8D6">                                    
                                    <td style="float:right;"><img src="~/Images/Field.png" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>              
       </tr>
```

Comment: Did you actually try anything by yourself? If yes, then please provide code you used.

Comment: Now i do like this Eg. $("#detailmain").append("<tr><td><table>......etc"); I don't think its only way to do this.